# Coat checks warning

Tags: theft, property, damages, disclaimers

I got into a debate with a friend about the disclaimer you see on coat checks, parking lot tickets, and other similar "contracts."  There is often text printed on the back of the tickets you receive.  Something along the line of, "We are not responsible for loss or damage."

As I understand, that is not legally binding.  When using their service, they are expected to provide a safe environment and if loss or damage occurs, they are responsible, regardless of the words on the ticket.

I expect this might vary from state to state, but is there a consensus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a bailment. There is a pretty general outcome.

First, I will discuss bailments. To get to the meat of the answer skip down to the horizontal break.

Here is some info from a Maryland case. I omitted citations and added emphasis. [Danner v. Int'l Freight Sys. of Washington](https://apps.fastcase.com/Research/Public/ExViewer.aspx?LTID=Zy2kLNaD1lgEQuiBRQXovj3iHNUVmRiEqI/gQ5RJRF6NTYv7kxgc6NGTk7qKJ%200gAd440anUWxVClyi5p1FntwK%20RW%204lBr/GAnnu3OPp//6kTA/48RstUgNMjQq%20dWjYGJBswAZVgbvI9BdJIcfj0GET6T9MTZmd4yS5/7r53M=), LLC (D. Md., 2012) *Maryland is a state which may honor the fine print*.

There are three types of bailments, the most common one is the type you are asking about, the bailment for mutual benefit. (You watch my coat, I give you a few dollars. As opposed to, "Hey will you watch my computer while I go to the bathroom?)

> A bailment relationship can arise in a variety of ways. In modern
>   usage, there are three general categories of bailments: (1) for the
>   sole benefit of the bailor; (2) for the sole benefit of the bailee;
>   and (3) for the mutual benefit of both.

The property should be returned in the same condition as it was delivered. A reasonable standard of care applies.

> When the subject matter of a mutual bailment for hire is delivered by
>   the bailor to the bailee, it must be returned by the bailee in
>   substantially the same condition ordinary wear and tear excepted. Put
>   another way, the bailee in accepting possession of the bailed property
>   assumes the duty of exercising **reasonable care** in protecting it.

If the property is damaged, the bailee (the person holding the coat) is automatically found to have failed to take reasonable care. They need to explain the damage and how it was not their fault. Then the bailor (the guy who owns the coat) needs to explain why, in spite of the excuses, the bailee is the one responsible.

> When the bailed chattel is either not returned or returned in a
>   damaged condition without legal excuse, a prima facie case of lack of
>   due care or negligence is made out. It is then the duty of the bailee
>   to go forward with proof that the loss or injury was occasioned by a
>   cause which excuses the bailee, thereby providing a **complete defense
>   as the bailee is not an insurer**. The bailor is then, by reason of
>   his burden of proof, required to overcome this defense by establishing
>   by a preponderance of the evidence that the bailee **failed to use
>   ordinary care and diligence** to safeguard the bailor's property, and
>   that failure to perform his duty caused the loss to the bailor.

So the bailee is responsible for negligence, but is not an insurer. As long as they provide the care that an ordinary person would provide in keeping their own coat, they are not responsible.

> A bailee may be liable for negligence, but is not strictly liable for
>   loss of bailed property. This is because a bailee for hire is not an
>   insurer of the safety of the property entrusted to its care, but . . .
>   **owes only such care as persons of common prudence in their own
>   situation** and business usually use in the custody and keeping of
>   similar property belonging to themselves.

---

Another case, this one from Washington, tells us a little about limiting liability. [Eifler v. Shurgard Capital Management Corp.](https://apps.fastcase.com/Research/Public/ExViewer.aspx?LTID=WX/CFJEnCWPs9CiANYtVZxk13Lg170jKBtvoKjPb2QRDh1wq9tY3SxBtxliJhcitpquGhitAiss/WKRYi%20pc2ZSRZ8KCNQ%20GeWKBHJJ/7qv0Fl3javHKlIdtzUU6i8ljiho4mVoGUos8mkeIQ3qUZxGtpVF8yaWxZCBzIVZ7hYM=), 861 P.2d 1071, (Wash.App. Div. 2, 1993) Again, internal quotes omitted and emphasis added. *These are the guys who do not honor the fine print*.

The case tells us that the bailee, if the bailee is a professional bailee, cannot limit liability.

> A professional bailee is one (1) whose principal business is to act as
>   bailee, and (2) who deals with the public on a uniform rather than
>   individual basis.
>   When a bailment for mutual benefit is also a professional bailment,
>   **public policy will not permit the bailee to limit his or her liability**
>   for negligence.

The court cites a popular leading California Supreme Court case ([Tunkl v. Regents of Univ. of Cal.](https://apps.fastcase.com/Research/Public/ExViewer.aspx?LTID=upYlfCcOZqozfTPwDhu12OJYx1wqlY3mjRg8KLL7mEnT7ymClihW5ncIvQlZeuGNK7ESjXHxG/ZLBIypFmHXTg742o0pjxw2s24SiTXWMaMEku4vxzFZU8ZsrWfA/lmT3seiZuscaIgwY9Xykwoco18/u8fLxQrwskO9D%20Aurno=), 60 Cal.2d 92 (1963)) and provides a "*test to be applied in determining whether exculpatory agreements violate public policy*" - in other words, if that fine print gets thrown out. The more of these elements that are true about the situation, the harder it is for the fine print to cover the bailee's ass:

1) Service to the public, perhaps even necessary to some
2) Offers the service to pretty much any customer
3) The bailee has a position of bargaining power by virtue of the service offering
4) Standard exculpatory language, take it or leave it
5) No option to pay more money for better protection
6) Property is placed under the control of the bailee

Bottom line is that if the state follows this model, the fine print is not enforceable.

> Thus, the attempted but invalid exemption involves a transaction which
>   exhibits some or all of the following characteristics. It concerns a
>   **business of a type generally thought suitable for public regulation**.
>   The party seeking exculpation is engaged in performing a service of
>   great importance to the public, which is often a **matter of practical
>   necessity** for some members of the public. The party holds himself out
>   as **willing to perform this service for any member of the public** who
>   seeks it, or at least for any member coming within certain established
>   standards. As a result of the essential nature of the service, in the
>   economic setting of the transaction, the party invoking exculpation
>   possesses a **decisive advantage of bargaining strength** against any
>   member of the public who seeks his services. In exercising a superior
>   bargaining power the party confronts the public with a **standardized
>   adhesion contract** of exculpation, and makes **no provision whereby a
>   purchaser may pay additional reasonable fees and obtain protection
>   against negligence**. Finally, as a result of the transaction, the
>   person or **property of the purchaser is placed under the control of the
>   seller**, subject to the risk of carelessness by the seller or his
>   agents.

Comment: The people looking after your coat wouldn’t be happy to look after a coat worth $100,000. Any idea what they would have to do to avoid liability for a ridiculously expensive coat?

Comment: @gnasher729 I am not that person but the answer does seem to basically say they have to treat it with due care and respect like they'd treat their own coat. I *expect* (and I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice) they are fine to treat it like any other coat regardless of value; if you want special treatment for your $100,000 coat you should not have given it to them, you should have paid extra for agreed special treatment, or you should have bought insurance.